# Django Singleton File API

Tags: python, django, api, caching, singleton

I'm attempting to create a sort of "cache" where an API uploads a file to the cache, and whenever a new file is uploaded it will replace the current file in the cache.  Only one file will be held at a time, and I can clear the cache when needed.  I'm not sure how to implement a singleton model that I upload to via an API. Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: There are a lot of different answers for this question depending on how your app is deployed. What's the purpose of this "cache"?

Comment: Thanks for asking! I'm storing ONIX book data in a single location that is waiting to be parsed and stored in a test book store.

Answer (score 0):

For Example, if you are using redis to cache. It can be as follows:

```
import redis
from django.http import FileResponse

r = redis.StrictRedis()
CACHING_FILE_KEY = 'something like this'
CACHING_FILE_NAME_KEY = 'something like that'

def upload(request):
    file = request.FILES["file"]
    filename = file.name
    content = b"".join(i for i in file.chunks())
    r.set(CACHING_FILE_KEY, content)
    r.set(CACHING_FILE_NAME_KEY, filename)
    return HttpResponse('ok')

def download(request):
    content = r.get(CACHING_FILE_KEY)
    filename = r.get(CACHING_FILE_NAME_KEY)
    response = FileResponse(content)
    response["Content-Type"] = "text/plain"
    response["Content-Length"] = len(content)
    response["Content-Disposition"] = f'attachment; filename={filename!r}'
    return response
```